# GUI SFTPs won't connect to a U22 virtual server from w11

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing, sftp, windows-11

I am trying to configure a U22.04 desktop running under virtual box as a file server, with a W11 client. I have installed a VBox bridged adaptor.

I have installed samba, open-ssh and sftpd. I am currently running all the services. I have created a share folder and set its permissions to 777, with ownership as root:sambashare. The user names on the windows system and ubuntu do not match. The ubuntu user is not a member of the samba share group.w11 w11

I can ssh onto the system using putty and the windows cli. I can sftp onto the system using the windows CLI sftp programme. I can ping the system. Putty accepted and stored the credentials,

Neither Filezilla, the W11 file explorer nor WinSCP can connect. I am using the ip address as the connection identity. I am specifying sftp protocol and logging in as the server user.

I believe that this is a server i.e. ubuntu configuration problem. Although with the file explorer it could be a credentials problem.

How can I get a file share service working?

If Ubuntu 22.04 is still restricted to smb1, then I am happy to abandon it, but I may still need nmbd, advice gratefully received.

I have checked previous posts, and don't think there is an Ubuntu server/virtual box one.

Dave

Comment: "I believe that this is a server i.e. ubuntu configuration problem"? Why? Did you check the logs of both server and client? Post the relevant logs here as well (as text using [code block]s please). You mention multiple protocols. Please focus this post on one of them

Comment: Did you configure samba for filesharing? Based on your post ssh works, but you don't indicate that you've attempted to configure samba filesharing?

Comment: If sftp from the Windows CLI works, but sftp from other Windows clients doesn't, then the first place I would look is the Windows firewall settings

Comment: There is no relationship between Samba and SFTP. They are different protocols. It's like saying, "I have a boat and a car. The car doesn't run." Are you using password or public private keys for ssh/sftp authentication?

Answer (score 0):

This is now working as expected. I was not very methodological about how I fixed it, but I believe the problem was caused by my failure to configure the ubuntu firewall correctly. Current default practice, at least, is to use **ufw**. I have made no changes to the windows firewall settings.

UFW comes with preconfigured named 'service' based rules; the commands I used were,

```
ufw allow OpenSSH
ufw allow Apache
ufw allow Samba
```

and for good measure in case I want printing `ufw allow CUPS`

then I ran

`ufw logging on`

then I ran `systemctl restart ufw`

for services without names one would need to specify the ports in the allow statement

@muru thank you for the advice to look at the logs, this was very helpful. Although I think that *ufw* defaults to unlogged activity, but I looked up what was there.

@vidario I had installed samba and configured it for name and file sharing, although at the moment I am using ip address names to connect from windows to linux.

Comment: Your answer could be improved for other readers by adding the specific commands you ran "to use ufw"